# Ylabel ticks position without object oriented format

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

This is the code i wrote. I need to locate the ylabel of imshow (the image at top-right) at bottom as in the image, while leaving the yticks with 0 at bottom and 5 on top. Another way could be to develop all this in an object explicit format, but I'm really dumb, so if you use it, please change all the plot positions so that i can still have the same figure.

`

```
fig = plt.figure("Field Configuration" + file_name)

    plt.subplot(5,2,(1,4))
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.4)
    font = {'family': 'serif', 'serif': ['Computer Modern'], 'weight' : 'bold', 'size' : 13}
    rc('font', **font)
    plt.suptitle(r'Field Configuration for $\beta$: '+str(i), x=0.93, y=.99, horizontalalignment='right')
    plt.title("X Sites", size=17)
    image = plt.imshow(field_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues) #, extent=[0,number_sites,0,number_sites])
    plt.colorbar(image, label='Spin Orientation')
    plt.ylabel("Y sites", size=17, loc='bottom')
    plt.clim(-1, +1)
```

[image]`

I tried looking on internet, but I'm really oblivious on how to us ax.subplots and specify a square subplot on top right and 2 horizontal rectangles at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options:

To invert axis only: use `extent` in `imshow`. This option can change x axis too

```
image = plt.imshow(field_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, extent=(-0.2, 9.8, -0.2, 9.8))
```

To invert axis and plot: use `origin` in `imshow`

```
image = plt.imshow(field_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, origin='lower')
```

Or, use the `invert_yaxis` method on axes object, without change `imshow`

```
image = plt.imshow(field_matrix, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

You can red the Doc:

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. Using just last method